# Smart pointer implementation: when is the destructor invoked for pointee?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the below code, and wrapped the `Temple` object with a smart pointer. I understood
the concept, but what I did not understand is when the held object's destructor is invoked.

Even thought, i have not implemented ~mySmartPointer, the template destructor is invoked.

### OUTPUT

> Temple Constructor
>
> Invoking pointer access operator
>
> -- Welcome Temple
>
> Invoking De-referencing Operator
>
> -- Welcome Temple
>
> **Temple Destructor**
>
> Destructor is Invoked

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class mySmartPointer 
{
private:
    T *_object;    
public: 
    explicit mySmartPointer(T * newObject) {
       _object = newObject;
    };
    ~mySmartPointer() { cout <<"Destructor is Invoked "<<endl;}; 

    T operator *() {
        cout  <<" Invoking De-referencing Operator "<<endl;
        return * _object;
    };

    T * operator ->() {
        cout <<"Invoking pointer access operator "<<endl;
        return _object;
    };
};

class Temple
{
private:
    int x,y;
public:
    void printWelcome() {
        cout <<"-- Welcome Temple "<<endl;
    }
    Temple() {
        cout <<"Temple Constructor"<<endl;
    }
    ~Temple() {
        cout <<"Temple Destructor "<<endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    mySmartPointer<Temple> t (new Temple);
    t->printWelcome();      
    (*t).printWelcome();
}
```

Comment: Once you've fixed that problem, have a look at the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Your pointer will go horribly wrong if it's copied.

Answer (score 7):

This

```
T operator *()
```

returns by value - and it's that copy that's being destroyed.

If you change it to

```
T& operator *()
```

you'll see it there'll be no destructor of the object invoked. Note that this should have two versions:

```
T const& operator *() const;
T& operator *()
```

and similar for `operator->`. This is so that you can call `const` methods on `const` objects.

If you're doing this for educational purposes, great, otherwise use one of the existing implementations.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that's causing the confusion.

```
  T operator *() 
  {
      cout  <<" Invoking De-referencing Operator "<<endl;
      return * _object;
  };
```

When you call this code, a **copy of Temple** is created.  This copy is getting destroyed automatically.

Change it to this:

```
  T& operator *() 
  {
      cout  <<" Invoking De-referencing Operator "<<endl;
      return * _object;
  };
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I have no control over that.  There were 0 answers.  I can delete my answer if you think I should.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're returning a *copy* of the object from `operator*()`.

Look at the return type here:

```
T operator *() 
{
     cout  <<" Invoking De-referencing Operator "<<endl;
     return * _object;
};
```

You need to return `T&` instead.

It is better if you define `T const & operator*() const`  also, for `const` smart pointer object!